# Angular :File reader of multiple files with FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader, formarray

I have a problem on uploading multiple images from different inputs, I have this form which contains a **formArray** to push a new input whenever I press "Add file" button

```
this.designForm = this.fb.group({
      newFiles: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control(null,Validators.required)
      ],Validators.required)
    });
  get newFiles() {
    return this.designForm.get('newFiles') as FormArray;
  }
  addNewFiles() {
    this.newFiles.push(this.fb.control(null,Validators.required));
  }
```

the button: `<button type="button" (click)="addNewFiles()">Add new Document</button>`

the input:

```
<div  *ngFor="let newFile of newFiles.controls; let i=index">
                    <input type="file" 
                    id="usecaseImage" 
                    (change)="showPreviewImage($event)"
                    [formControlName]="i">
                </div>
```

and the event method:

```
showPreviewImage(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
          for(let i=0;i<this.newFiles.length;i++){
            console.log(this.newFiles.length);
            this.designForm.value.newFiles[i] = event.target.result; 
          }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);   
    }
}
```

it works for uploading but then when I try to preview the image it just repeat the last image from the last input so if I have 3 inputs with values

> input1 value-> X.JPG, input2 value-> Y.JPG and input3 value-> Z.JPG

it previews Z.JPG 3 times!

**Edit:** the preview is in another component which I fill it from the service from the original component :
`this.designForm = this.sdlcService.designForm ;`

then I am looping to get how many forms I have (how many times I submitted the form) and another loop to get how many inputs in the single form (how many images uploaded) using keyvalue pipe to extract the values.

```
<div *ngFor="let form of designForm ;let d = index">
              <img [src]="input.value" *ngFor="let input of form | keyvalue;let s = index">
            </div>
```

**How should I handle this?**

Comment: where is preview html code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here a typical solution (in **Angular**)

*template*

```
<button class="" (click)="uploader.click()">
      <input hidden type="file" multiple #uploader (change)="onFileInputChange($event)" />
</button>
```

*ts*

```
attachments: File[] = [];
----------------------------
onFileInputChange($event: any) {
 if (!$event.target.files) {
   return;
 }
 Array.from($event.target.files).forEach((f: File) => {
   if (!this.attachments.find((i) => i.name === f.name)) {
    this.attachments.push(f);
   }
 });
}


async onSubmit() {
   if (!this.attachments.length) {
      return;
   }

   const attachments = await Promise.all(this.attachments.map(this.fileToDataURL));        
      // add any action you want, here you got an array of dataUri
 }



fileToDataURL(file_: File) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file_);
      reader.addEventListener(
        'load',
        function (event) {
          resolve(event.target.result);
        },
        false,
      );
    });
  }
```